# Three.js seeing faces that are behind others

Tags: three.js

http://trumpetr.com/three.js-master/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
It's a program that takes a polygon and rotates it around an axis. For some reason, when viewing from the top, you can see the faces that should be hidden. Also, the side faces flicker a ton. Earlier, I has some trouble with defining the vertices of the triangles in counter-clockwise order, but I'm pretty sure I've fixed that.

Comment: Assuming you have no erors in your model, that is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`. Can you switch to `WebGLRenderer`?

Comment: THANK YOU! Is it that CanvasRender doesn't have occlusion culling?

Comment: There was a problem, but I think I solved it. I just had to change it to DoubleSide instead of FrontSide.

Comment: What is the question you want me to answer?

Comment: That was it, you solved it. Thanks!